# Options in documentclass in pylatex

Tags: python, pylatex

I do not understand the documentation of `pylatex`. I'm using `pylatex`.

How do I change the page orientation and font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor `Document` does not support options for the document class. However, the `documentclass` is available as `Command` and can be overwritten:

```python
    doc = Document('basic')
    doc.documentclass = Command(
        'documentclass',
        options=['12pt', 'landscape'],
        arguments=['article'],
    )
```

Also a package like `geometry` can be added, see the following example, which was derived from the basic and full example of the documentation of [`pylatex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyLaTeX):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Package, Command
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape


def fill_document(doc):
    """Add a section, a subsection and some text to the document.

    :param doc: the document
    :type doc: :class:`pylatex.document.Document` instance
    """
    with doc.create(Section('A section')):
        doc.append('Some regular text and some ')
        doc.append(italic('italic text. '))

        with doc.create(Subsection('A subsection')):
            doc.append('Also some crazy characters: $&#{}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Basic document
    doc = Document('basic')
    doc.documentclass = Command(
        'documentclass',
        options=['12pt', 'landscape'],
        arguments=['article'],
    )
    fill_document(doc)
    doc.packages.append(Package('geometry',
        options=['a6paper', 'showframe']))

    doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
    doc.generate_tex()
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

In PyLaTeX [>1.1.0](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/changelog.html#docs-2016-12-09) the [constructor of the Document class](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/pylatex/pylatex.document.html) allows to provide document_options as a list:

```python
from pylatex import Document

doc = Document(inputenc="utf8", documentclass="scrarticle", document_options=["12pt", "landscape"])
```

Edit: PyLatex 1.1.0 was released few weeks after @heiko-oberdiek answered.